# Email Delivery Settings Salesforce

Tags: sales-cloud

[image]

Started seeing this from yesterday in full sandbox and not in the dev box.
Just wondering how a new feature has come up in the last 2 days in to Salesforce as it was not part of any maintenance. We are on CS6.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Someone from System Admin profile has activated Email Relay.

So, before activation, you will see a menu link (*Email Relay Activation*). After clicking that link following screen is displayed.

[image: Email Relay]

And finally, activating email replay, you will see "**Email Delivery Settings**" menu as you have posted.

[image: Email Admin]

You can replicate this scenario at your DE.

Comment: I tried this in my development environment and it did not make any difference. I can still only see the old email relay activation menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it because of activation/deactivation. 
It happens because we hit the 'Try it now' for the new features.